# Identify dictionaries when one of the values are the same in a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In my current list of dicts, all dictionaries contain different values except for 'name':

```
list_dicts = [{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat']},
                 {'id': 678910, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['zebra']},
                 {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse']},
                 {'id': 141516, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['rabbit']}]
```

I would like to create a new list of dictionaries where only one of the dictionaries with the repeated names exists.

**Desired output:**

```
output_list_dicst = [{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat']},
                     {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse']}]
```

**Current code:** I tried to create a new list of dicts if the d['name'] does not exist there.

```
output = []
    for d in list_dicts:
        if d['name'] not in output: #if the name value is not existing (yet), append d to output
            output.append(d)
```

This doesn't work but I think I am thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the direction is right, just you were checking for a string (name), but adding objects to a list. Instead you would need something where you are adding names and objects in pairs, in a way you can check for the presence of the name. Like a dict:

```
list_dicts = [{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat']},
                 {'id': 678910, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['zebra']},
                 {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse']},
                 {'id': 141516, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['rabbit']}]

output = {}
for d in list_dicts:
    if d['name'] not in output:
        output[d['name']]=d

print(output)
```

then you have a dict, and you can get its values to have the filtered list you wanted:

```
actuallist=list(output.values())
print(actuallist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right, the problem is, that you are checking whether the name is in `output`, but you are adding the dicts to the output. Do this instead:

```
known_name = set()
[known_name.add(dct["name"]) or dct
 for dct in list_dicts 
 if dct["name"] not in known_name]
```

`known_name` just collects the names so we can keep track of them. Then the list comprehensions only keeps the new dicts. `known_name.add(dct["name"])` adds the name to the known name list and returns `None`, so `known_name.add(dct["name"]) or dct` adds to known_name, but ultimately evaluates to `dct`.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = []
for d in list_dicts:
  t = [temp_dict['name'] for temp_dict in output]
  if d['name'] not in t:
    output.append(d)
```

I am first extracting all the different values of 'name' stored in output till now and then checking if the current 'name' exists in it or not.